# CDF, expectation and variance of density $g(y)=\frac{k}{(1+y)^{k+1}}\mathbb{1}_{y>0}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If this is a standard density for a named distribution this question would possibly be redundant but I couldn't find it when I looked.

$Y$ has density $g(y)=\frac{k}{(1+y)^{k+1}}\mathbb{1}_{y>0}$ where the $1$ is an indicator function. I think the first bits below are OK, but I don't think I a close to getting the variance.

CDF: 
$$\mathbb{P}(X<x) = \int_0^x \frac{k}{(1+y)^{k+1}}\mathrm{dy} = 
\bigg[ \frac{-1}{(1+y)^k}  \bigg]^x_0 = \frac{-1}{(1+x)^k}+1
$$

Expectation Using substitution $u=1+y$ so $\mathrm{du}= \mathrm{dy}$:
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_0^\infty \frac{ky}{(1+y)^{k+1}}
=k\int_1^\infty \frac{u-1}{u^{k+1}}\mathrm{du} = k\int_1^\infty u^{-k}-u^{-(k+1)}\mathrm{du}
$$
$$=k\bigg[\frac{u^{-(k-1)}}{-(k-1)}  -\frac{u^{-k}}{-k}  \bigg]_1^\infty
= k\bigg((0-0) - \big(\frac{-1}{k-1} -\frac{-1}{k}  \big) \bigg) = 1-\frac{k}{k-1} = \frac{-1}{k-1} = \frac{1}{1-k}
$$
This looks like a nice answer, but I am not very confident.

Variance - will need to calculate the expectation of $Y^2$ I think
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = \int_0^\infty\frac{ky^2}{(1+y)^(k+1)} \mathrm{dy}
= k \int_1^\infty \frac{u^2-2u+1}{u^{k+1}} \mathrm{du}
= k \int_1^\infty  u^{1-k} -2 u^{-k} + u^{-(k+1)}\mathrm{du}
= k \bigg[ \frac{u^{2-k}}{2-k} +\frac{2u^{1-k}}{1-k}+  \frac{u^{-k}}{-k} \bigg]_1^\infty
= 0+0+0 +\frac{k^2\cdot (1-k)+2k^2(2-k)+k(1-k)(2-k)}{-k(1-k)(2-k)}
= \frac{k-k^2 + 4k-2k^2+2-3k+k^2}{-(1-k)(2-k)} = \frac{2k^2-2k-2}{(1-k)(2-k)}
$$

As variance $= \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2$ we get

$$
\frac{2k^2-2k-2}{(1-k)(2-k)} - \frac{1}{(1-k)^2} = 
\frac{(2k^2-2k-2)(1-k)-2+k}{(1-k)^2(2-k)} =
\frac{(2k^2-2k-2  -2k^3+2k^2+2k-2+k}{(1-k)^2(2-k)} 
= \frac{-2k^3+4k^2+k-4}{(1-k)^2(2-k)} 
$$

So now I am fairly confident I have gone wrong, but I htink it is in the $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$ rather than this algebra.

I would like to know where I went wrong. Also could this be done with a generating function approach for the distribution, or using the characteristic function or moment generating function. Would these latter be more straightforward? I am less familiar with them.

Also if this is a named distribution, what is it? Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagum_distribution - with $a=b=1$ and $p=k$.

Comment: If $k>1$ you should have $\mathbb E[Y]=\frac1{k-1}$ - note that $\frac1{1-k}$ would be negative, which cannot be true if $\mathbb P(Y>0)=1$.